# How to share video (.mp4) to social media in Android App?

Tags: android, android-intent, video, android-sharing

I've looked in stackoverflow and saw some posts on how to share a video from the phone to another app, but none seem to work. I followed the following guide: http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent/ but this also appears to not work. Does anyone have a short snippet of code to properly share a video? The following does not work with SMS Messaging, Inbox, Gmail, Google+, Facebook, or Messenger.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/video.mp4");

sharingIntent.setType("video/mp4");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, videoUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share video using"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the rest of your code or the error stacktrace is difficult to tell what is going wrong.

But I would say maybe check the Uri you are providing is right and the video path matches with that one.